# How to use scrapy with html content

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright

I have written a code using playwright that returns html content.
My question is if there is a method to call scrapy to read from this html content or scrapy reads only from urls ?

I will apreciate any answer from you.

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest write that returned HTML content to a file and
use this to scrape local file using:

```
import scrapy
import os

LOCAL_FILENAME = 'example.html'
LOCAL_FOLDER = 'html_files'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    start_urls = [
        f"file://{BASE_DIR}/{LOCAL_FOLDER}/{LOCAL_FILENAME}"
    ]
```